# Return data from MongoDB to jade view

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

All the pieces are almost in place but something is breaking. I'm attempting to pass the data from a mongo collection back to the jade view, however Jade is returning the below error:

```
TypeError: /Users/rhysedwards/Downloads/insightful/food/views/index.jade:30
    28|       
    29|       #events
  > 30|       each Entry, i in entries
    31|         div.title
    32|         div.url
    33|         div.specificDate

Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

Am I correctly calling the database in the router and returning the data back correctly? If anyone could clarify that would be great.

Router:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next){
  var db = req.db;
  var entries = db.get('entries');
  entries.find( function (err, entries) {
    res.render('index', {
      "entries": entries
    });
  });
});
```

Jade template

```
each entry, i in entries
  div.title
  div.url      
  div.selectedDate
```

Data in Entries collection

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56fae2731b90abc3793d4f33"),
    "url" : "https://www.residentadvisor.net/event.aspx?801261",
    "title" : "\tRA Tickets: Sneak Every Tuesday at XOYO, London",
    "selectedDate" : "03/09/2016",
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Schema

```
var Entry = module.exports = mongoose.model('Entry', EntrySchema);
```

Comment: You can log (`console.dir`) the `err` and `entries` to check if something is wrong before calling `render`.

Answer (score 0):

(Updated) Isn't the correct usage of `find()` as follows?

```
  entries.find({}, function (err, entries) {
    res.render('index', {
      "entries": entries
    });
  });
```

Comment: Tried it both ways and `entries` still comes back as undefined within Jade

Comment: find(callback) is the same as find({}, callback).

Comment: My bad! Then you will need to check for error: `console.log(err)`.